# Пропал проект Git

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

Делал проект в phpStorm, сделал commit, он отобразился в истории, потом запушил проект на gitHub, но там почему-то оказалась только часть проекта. В попытках решить эту проблему ввел команду `git checkout remote/origin`, и весь проект пропал. Есть ли возможность его восстановить?

Comment: Проверьте локальную ветку в git, скорее всего она называется master

Comment: я ввожу команду git checkout master, и ничего не меняется

Answer (score 4):

Сделал `git reflog`, а потом `git checkout <хэш коммита>`, это помогло восстановить коммит.

Comment: Полезная команда :) Подробнее: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%A3%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85